# Deductions about the prime factorization of odd integers $m>1$ satisfying $\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}(p-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

For each integer $m>1$ we denote the Euler's totient function as $\varphi(m)$ and the product of distinct primes dividing it, that is its square-free kernel, as $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ (that is the arithmetic function explained in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)). Thus for our integer $m>1$ one has $$\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(m))=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}(p-1).$$

While I was calculating solutions of some equations that involves* the arithmetic function $\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(n))$ and the sum of divisors and totatives for even perfect numbers, I got also odd solutions of next equation $$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8n}}{2}=\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(n)).\tag{1}$$

The odd solutions of $(1)$ that I can to calculate are $n=45$ and $n=3321$. These solutions have the form $q\cdot t^2$, being $q$ an odd prime $\equiv 1\text{ mod }4$ and $\gcd(q,t)=1$, in fact in previous solutions $t$ is a power of $3$. I would like to know what work can be done about the characterization of such odd solutions, if there are more odd integers being solutions.

> **Question.** Imagine that we need to study the odd integers $m>1$ satisfying $(1)$. What can we deduce about such odd solutions $m$? I am asking about their prime factorization. **Many thanks.**

One has thus that we need to study the prime factorization of odd integers $m$ that satisfy $$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}(p-1).\tag{2}$$

Comment: *The equations that I evoke (thus comment this isn't directly related to previous $(1)$ and the Question), and that satisfy each even perfect numbers $e$ are this $\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+4\sigma(e)}}{2}=\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(e))$ being $\sigma(n)$ the sum of divisors function, and thisone $2(e-1)-\varphi(e)=\left(\frac{11+3\sqrt{1+8e}}{8}\right)\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(e))$. I add this comment as context, and as a comparison of previous equations, $(1)$ is the simplest equation, but there exist (odd) integers satisfying it that aren't even perfect numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calculation shows that$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\phi(rad(m))$$for odd $m= $$$45$$$$3321$$$$926510115949281$$$$1716841910146257168839018970561$$These numbers have the form $$\frac{3^n(3^n+1)}{2}$$for even $n=2, 4, 16, 32$, respectively.

Note that $m$ is thus the $3^nth$ triangle number. Indeed, $\sqrt{1+8m}$ is an integer only if odd $m$ is triangular, since for integer $k$$$\sqrt{1+\frac{8k(k+1)}{2}}=\sqrt{4k^2+4k+1}=\sqrt{(2k+1)^2}=2k+1$$

Factoring the four $m$:$$45=3^2(3^2+1)/2=3^2\cdot 5$$$$3321=3^4(3^4+1)/2=3^4\cdot 41$$$$926510115949281=3^{16}(3^{16}+1)/2=3^{16}\cdot  21523361$$$$1716841910146257168839018970561=3^{32}(3^{32}+1)/2=3^{32}\cdot 926510094425921$$For even $n$ from $2$ through $32$, only these four $m$ have the form $3^np$, i.e are composed of a power of $3$ and a single odd prime $p$.

This condition appears to be sufficient for$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\phi(rad(m))$$and can be proven as follows:

If $$m=3^np$$ then $$rad(m)=3p$$and$$\phi(rad(m))=(3-1)(p-1)=2p-2$$

And again, if$$\sqrt{1+8m}=\sqrt{1+8\cdot \frac{3^n(3^n+1)}{2}}=\sqrt{1+8\cdot \frac{3^{2n}+3^n}{2}}=\sqrt{4\cdot 3^{2n}+4\cdot 3^n+1}=2\cdot 3^n+1$$then$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\frac{-3+2\cdot 3^n+1}{2}=3^n-1$$And since$$p=\frac{3^n+1}{2}$$then$$3^n-1=2p-2$$as above, and$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\phi(rad(m))$$for all odd $m=3^np$.

Note that $n$ must be even, since if $n$ is odd, then $3^n+1=0(mod4)$, making $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ even and hence not an odd prime.

At first, I expected the equation might hold for all $n$ equal to a power of $2$, but $n=8$ does not work. Primes are infinitely many, but if we cannot know the law of even $n$ for which $(3^n+1)/2$ is prime, then even if $$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\phi(rad(m))$$is true for infinitely many odd $m$, it seems that, like the primes themselves, we will have to find them one at a time.

**addendum**

Further calculation reveals that $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$=  $$1716841910146256242328924544641$$is prime for $n=64$, when $m$=$$5895092288869291585760436430707976174749252052380249479093121$$But $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ is not prime for $n=128, 256, 512$ or $1024$.

More importantly, it appears--and I suppose it can be proven--that $5$ is a divisor of $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ not only for $n=2$ but for every $n$ which is an odd multiple of $2$. And since all these increasingly large $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ must contain other prime factors besides $5$, they cannot be prime.  This rules out $$n=6, 10, 14, 18, 22...$$or one half of all even $n$, less one.

Similarly, $41$ is a divisor of $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ for $n=4$ and all odd multiples of $4$, so that $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ cannot be prime when $n$ is an odd multiple of $4$. This rules out half of the remaining even $n$, less one$$12, 20, 28, 36, 44...$$

Again, since $17$ and $193$ divide $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ for $n=8$, as well as for all odd multiples of $8$, then$$8, 24, 40, 56, 72...$$or exactly half of the remaining $n$ are ruled out.

Accordingly, since $n$ is even, and an even number which is not an odd multiple of $2, 4, 8, 16, 32 ...$ must be a power of $2$, it seems a necessary but insufficient condition of the primality of $\frac{3^n+1}{2}$ that $n$ be a power of $2$.

Hence, like the Fermat primes, the odd $m$ for which$$\frac{-3+\sqrt{1+8m}}{2}=\phi(rad(m))$$are not only rare, but perhaps finite in number.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention, calculations and reasonings.

Comment: @user243301 If you want, you can $\color{green}{\text{accept}}$ this answer :)